# PHP Redirect header what is HTTP/1.1

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers

```
header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header("Location: xxxxxx"); //Destination
```

What is HTTP/1.1

reference : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301

Comment: It is the version of the http protocol to be used. This is specified to make sure that client and server speak the same language, when it comes to details.

Comment: it's HTTP version. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#History

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTTP 1.1** is the **latest version of Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP)**, the World Wide Web application protocol that runs on top of the Internet's TCP/IP suite of protocols. HTTP 1.1 provides faster delivery of Web pages than the original HTTP and reduces Web traffic. Developed by a committee of the Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF) that includes the Web's chief creator Tim Berners-Lee, HTTP 1.1 is supported by the latest Web servers and browsers.